# How to wait until file is downloaded and also wait until the file is deleted from folder in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, wait, webdriverwait

Have to download a file in multiple formats xls, pdf, rtf, csv, txt. But I have to check all these file formats are downloaded one after another

So I have written below code which gets executed after **Download** button is clicked. But I want the system to wait until the file is downloaded completely and also wait until the file is deleted from folder. Only after file is deleted I want to click **Download** button again

```
File dir = new File(folderPath);
dirContents = dir.listFiles();
int dirContentsSize = dirContents.length;

for (int k = 0; k < dirContents.length; k++) 
{
    String fileName = dirContents[k].getName();
    System.out.println(fileName + " identified");
    dirContentsSize = dirContents.length;
    boolean isFileDeleted = dirContents[k].delete();
    if (isFileDeleted)
    System.out.println(fileName + " successfully deleted file");
}
```

Kindly help

Comment: you can use while loop use counters up to 10 or whatever number you used Than put thread.sleep() inside while loop, and check until that file is present on that desired folder.

Answer (score 0):

The following code which involves **do while** is working fine where it checks if the file is not directory and file names doesn't contain temporary filename **crdownload** prior to deleting the file. Before the delete file command is executed it keeps on checking for the above 2 conditions.

```
                    do {
                        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                            
                            if (!file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().contains("crdownload")) {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                                file.delete();
                                System.out.println(reportName + " " + file.getName() + " deleted successfully");
                            }
                        }    
                    } while (dir.listFiles().length != 0);
```